# Minecraft Christmas: Is there a way to grab the chest textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to grab the Christmas textures of the chests in Minecraft?

Picture of the chests:
[image: Chests!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its located in Windows at `%appdata%/roaming/.minecraft/versions/1.7.4/1.7.4.jar`.
Open your minecraft.jar file (currently `1.7.4.jar`) with WinRAR, and go to the following folder: `assets\minecraft\textures\entity\chest`. In that folder there are some files which two of them are named `christmas.png` and `"christmas_double.png"`.
Here is a copy of the textures:
**normal chest:**
[image: normal chest]
**double chest:**
[image: double chest]

Comment: Wonderful!  I can now spread christmas joy!